# How can XLST match two XML nodes via their attributes?

Tags: xslt

I've got an XML that I'm trying to transform which contains a relation between different nodes, related via ID, but I can't figure out how to 'glue' them together.

XML example:

```
<order>
 <products>     
  <product id="1234">
   <item quantity="5" colour="red">
   <item quantity="2" colour="blue">
  </product> 
  <product id="9876">
   <item quantity="10" colour="teal">
  </product>
 </products>

 <prices>
  <productprice>
   <refProduct id="1234" />
   <price gross="9.99" />
  </productprice>
  <productprice>
   <refProduct id="9876" />
   <price gross="6.89" />
  </productprice>
 </prices>
</order>
```

My desireable outcome would be something like being able to display the products via a for-each, with their respective prices listed next to them.

Any clues gratefully received.

EDIT: fixed renegade products element, example should be well formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple proof of concept for making the connection you wanted. The input XML wasn't well formed so I made the assumption there was only one products element, with multiple product children.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <products>
            <xsl:for-each select="order/products/product">
                <product>
                    <xsl:variable name="productid" select="@id"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$productid"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="price">
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select="/order/prices/productprice[refProduct[@id = $productid]]/price/@gross"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </product>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </products>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It results in the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
    <product id="1234" price="9.99"/>
    <product id="9876" price="6.89"/>
</products>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML isn't well-formed, which makes it hard to answer the question exactly. But something along the lines of this maybe?

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <out>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </out>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/root/order/products/product">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="string(@id)" />
    <prod id="{@id}">
      <xsl:value-of select="/root/prices/productprice[refProduct/@id=$id]/price/@gross" />
    </prod>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously the exact XPath will be different depending on how your XML is structured, but something like this will match product to price. You could move it out into a function if you do need to iterate over products.

Comment: you got me on the formedness, bang to rights. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In terms on looking up elements, this is an ideal situation for using **xsl:key**. So, for your sample, you might want to look up prices for a product, so you would define your key like so

```
<xsl:key name="prices" match="productprice" use="refProduct/@id" />
```

So, this will allow you to access **productprice** elements, by using the value of a product id. Specifically, if you were positioned on a **product** element, you would access the key to get the gross price like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('prices', @id)/price/@gross" />
```

As for displaying products, generally speaking it is often preferable to use **xsl:apply-templates** over **xsl:for-each** as it is more within the 'spirit' of XSLT.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="products/product" />
```

Templates can be called in multiple places to cut down on code duplication, and it can make code more readable, especially by reducing code indentation.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="prices" match="productprice" use="refProduct/@id" />

   <xsl:template match="/order">
      <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="products/product" />
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="product">
      <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="key('prices', @id)/price/@gross" /></td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following well-formed XML

```
<order>
   <products>
      <product id="1234">
         <item quantity="5" colour="red"/>
         <item quantity="2" colour="blue"/>
      </product>
      <product id="9876">
         <item quantity="10" colour="teal"/>
      </product>
   </products>
   <prices>
      <productprice>
         <refProduct id="1234"/>
         <price gross="9.99"/>
      </productprice>
      <productprice>
         <refProduct id="9876"/>
         <price gross="6.89"/>
      </productprice>
   </prices>
</order>
```

The following is output

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td>9.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>6.89</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, I agree entirely about the xsl:apply-templates approach, flat is better than nested, as the zen of python wisely states ;) I'm writing the transformation for (notionally) semi-technical users to edit, so I'm weighing up the simplicity of the presentation.